# Using T4 to generate Autometadata from a dbml file that exists in another dll

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, t4

I have two DLLs

1. BLL : business layer contains EDMX file for Entity Framework file
2. MVC3 : contains asp.net mvc application

Currently I put Autometadata.tt file inside BLL so I can generate AutoMetaData classes depending on the EDMX file. But I want to have AutoMetaData file inside MVC3 application and still generate files depending on the EDMX file existed in BLL dll

Can we do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can do that.

All you need to do is retrive important data using reflection from other assembly and generate classes depending on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply referencing the edmx file from your template, then you can reach across the relative path between the projects just by playing with the path that you use to load the edmx file, for example:

```
var inputFile = @"..\..\BLLsFolder\Bll1Project\BLL1Model.edmx";
```

Obviously this is a bit of nasty coupling, but it should generally work.

Alternatively, j.salawa's solution should also be OK - you might want to check out the following question for a little more info on that approach:
[Q11371641](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371641/an-academic-query-about-t4-templates)